# How do I initialize an IXMLDOMNode in VBA?

Tags: xml, vba, ixmldomnode

When I use the this code in an Excel VBA macro:

```
Dim xmlKnoten As New IXMLDOMNode
```

I always get an error. How do I initiate it right?

The initiation of an `DOMDocument` works:

```
Dim xmlDoc As Object
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Have you checked [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms765513(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, ensure you have the *Microsoft XML* reference enabled (my version is *v3.0*). Once you have that enabled, your code should work, but if it doesn't you can write it like this:

```
Dim xmlKnoten As New MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
```

Hope that helps.